# Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

the system used to work correctly, but then this error occurs I had no idea for the solution since i'm still new to this platform; but I've checked similar issue that suggested its due to missing file directory. Any suggestion?

Attached is the File structure;
These files are under a system file[Files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSlzv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occures due to the following reasons.

- your **system** folder might be missing
- Check your permission of folders
- Open your index.php file and find $system_path and
  $application_folder.

`$system_path = 'system';
    $application_folder = 'application';`

Answer (score 2):

point your system folder correctly, if it is different directory adjust that in the index.php

e.g

```
$system_path = 'system';

$system_path = '../system';

$system_path = '../../system';
```

Comment: Nicely pointed, also permission sometimes webserver user may not have sufficient privilege to read system directory ++

Answer (score 0):

This occures due to the following reasons.

```
your system folder might be missing
```

1. open config
2. and config.php
3. search $config['index_page'] = '';
4. last search input index.php for example $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CI4, create index.php inside project main dir:

```
<?php

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Ensure the current directory is pointing to the front controller's directory
chdir(__DIR__);

// Load our paths config file
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsConfig = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
// ^^^ Change this if you move your application folder
require realpath($pathsConfig) ?: $pathsConfig;

$paths = new Config\Paths();

// Location of the framework bootstrap file.
$bootstrap = rtrim($paths->systemDirectory, '\\/ ') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php';
$app       = require realpath($bootstrap) ?: $bootstrap;

  
$app->run();
```