# uploading codeigniter project with database on 000webhost

Tags: codeigniter

The following error occurred while running the URl of my codeigniter project with database  in 000webhost, the configuration of the database is given below.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'id4100798_skyloade_msd',
    'password' => '******',
    'database' => 'id4100798_skyloade_msd',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

it give the following error when we browse the url

error :

**Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Data**

URL:
https://medicalsociodoc.000webhostapp.com/SiteController

it is working fine on localhost.

Comment: Check model name in controller and model if in small letter make in upper case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417240/your-application-folder-path-does-not-appear-to-be-set-correctly-please-open-th

Comment: Thank you its work for me @Artier